# Unable to receive burst of 1 packet with rte_eth_rx_burst

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to receive packets transmitted by another DPDK application on different system. I am able transmit a burst value of 1 packet with rte_eth_tx_burst Api, but unable to receive with burst value of 1 in rte_eth_rx_burst Api. I am able to receive packets only if rx_burst value is 4 or higher than that. Is it because of any ethdev configuration?

Comment: Can you be bit more elaborate of your problem ?What paramteres you are passing to rte_eth_rx_brust(). In my application I am able to receive and transmit of only one 1 pkt. Can you try defining an array size of one for rx_burst packet like below. struct rte_mbuf *pkts_burst[1]; rte_eth_rx_burst(port_id, local_targetid, pkts_burst, 1);

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Issue is in i40e driver code where they fixed RTE_I40E_DESCS_PER_LOOP to 4.I changed that to 1 and I am able receive packet burst of 1

Answer (score 1):

ixgbe i40e device have the problem, virtio-net hasn't the problem. modify RTE_*_DESCS_PER_LOOP in file *_rxtx.h.